# Discrete Weights and Activations in Tensorflow or Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

Do you know about a way to constrain `tensorflow` or `keras` to a set of discrete weights and use discrete/rigid activation functions (e.g. like `sign` or `hard-tanh`)?

The APIs seem to have only smooth activation functions.

What I also thought about is to discretize the weights via a custom regularization function, but I don't know how to make the frameworks take this into account.

Probably I'll have to extend the (for example) Dense Layer class (of the respective framework) and define a custom forward-propagation function (and its derivative). Do you have any examples for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion changing weights and activations from smooth to discrete ones might be a huge problem in Keras. I see at least two major difficulties in this approach:

1. **Optimization framework must be completely different:** the main reason why Keras / Theano does so good job in ANN is the fact that they are able to automatically differentate tensor functions. This is the main building block for most of today's optimization algorithms. Changing domain from continous to discrete one changes rules of optimization and, as far as I know, Keras & Theano are not prepared for this.
2. **Mathematical issues:** you may wonder if simply rounding every weight and activiation might be a good solution for your problem. But you have to remember that highly dimensional discrete grids have some counterintuitive properties which may be really misleading. E.g. diameter of 28 x 28 x 3 dimensional unit cube is 50 and has enormous big number of vertexes (`2^dimension`).

These are the reasons why solution of your problem might be really difficult.

Comment: You are right. It seems to be impossible. I've found a blogpost that shows how to quantize a model after having trained with continuous values:
https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/

Comment: However, training directly with discrete weights seems to need a completely different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Both activations and more are possible in Tensorflow using a combination of functions.  For the two examples you cite:

```
zero = tf.constant(0)
one = tf.constant(1)
neg_one = tf.constant(-1)

hard_tanh(x) = tf.minimum(tf.maximum(x, neg_one), one)) 

sign(x) = tf.greater(x, zero)
```

Note that the latter returns a boolean tensor, so if you need ones and zeros or ones and minus ones you can use tf.cast to change the data type and shift appropriately.  All of these functions have gradients implemented.

For discrete weights, I suppose you could apply an appropriate discrete activation to the weights before using them.  That approach works for things like non-negative matrix factorization where you zero out the negative weights in each update step using rectified linear units.